# How can I use two pivot, or panorama item like one?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to create a progmram like a Peole. At there you can watch the recent call in two panorama item. How Did they do this?
So I use forexample a stack or wrappanel in two panorama items, when you do to the next page, at there also will be the stackpanel from the first page.

Help me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Recent' tab in People hub is just one PanoramaItem.

You should use `WrapPanel` with `Orientation` set to `Horizontal` to get that kind of effect.